# Best way to avoid fake users

Tags: unique, uniqueidentifier

I'm developing a web app where it's crucial that the users can't register twice (e.g., with different emails).

I'd like to use some automated way to check it's unique.

Checking Personal Identification Number (like in Passport), isn't a good idea, because it must be done manually, since gov sites use captchas.

What is the best way to achieve it?

To be more specific, what is a field that I can use with UNIQUE constraint in my users table?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there is no single answer to your question. Tax systems use VAT code, medical systems use Social Security Numbers, Universities use Student-ID etc.

Depending on your application, you could try to see if [OpenID](http://openid.net/add-openid/) would be suitable. It provides an easy sign-in mechanism for your site. OpenID will give you a lot of information about the user and also the advantage of access to social networking data which may be valuable to your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example use DBMS and keep an eye on users registrations. For more info see msdn SQL Server